# So the total number of points of $Q$ is $\frac{p-1}{2} \cdot \frac{q-1}{2}$

Tags: number-theory

[image]

We consider the line $(E): y=\frac{q}{p}x$

At the rectangle $Q=\{(x,y)|0<x<p/2, 0<y<p/2\}$ the number of points with integer coordinates 
is $\frac{p-1}{2} \cdot \frac{q-1}{2}$.

We have $\frac{p-1}{2}$ columns and each column has $\frac{q-1}{2}$ points.

There are no points at $Q$ with integer coordinates that are at the line $(E)$.

The number of points that are under the line $(E)$ is equal to $$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{[\frac{qk}{p}]}$$

And the number of points that are above the line $(E)$ is equal to $$\sum_{l=1}^{\frac{q-1}{2}}{[\frac{pl}{q}]}$$

So the total number of points of $Q$ is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{[\frac{qk}{p}]}+\sum_{l=1}^{\frac{q-1}{2}}{[\frac{pl}{q}]}=\frac{p-1}{2} \cdot \frac{q-1}{2}$$

Could you explain me the last relation??

Comment: Obviously, there is a typo in the last line.

Comment: I edited my post..

Comment: number of points = number of points under the line + number of points on the line + number of points above the line

Comment: Ok! I understand!!! And something else...why do we consider this line, $(E):y=\frac{q}{p}x$?